# PowerShell Export-Csv can't work with UseQuotes parameter

Tags: windows, windows-7, powershell-5.0, export-csv

I'm trying to start this from my Powershell script:

```
Import-Csv -Path $filecur -Delimiter ";" | Export-Csv -Path $filenext -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode -UseQuotes Never
```

But after executing Powershell script command promt show the next text:

```
Export-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'UseQuotes'.
At C:\Users\vad\Desktop\QuatesDeleter.ps1:4 char:116
+ ... ilenext -Delimiter ";" -notypeinfo -Encoding Unicode -UseQuotes Never
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

How can I solve this problem? 
My computer is running under Windows 7, SP1, X64, PowerShell version is 5.1.14409.1005.

In Microsoft documentation I could't find some information about this problem

[Link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's neccesary to install PowerShell version 7.x (PowerShell Core).

Comment: Use PS $PSVersionTable to check the version of your PowerShell using the PowerShell command prompt.